# how to write XOR in assembly(ARM)

Tags: assembly, arm, xor, instruction-set, instructions

I want to get xor value of two register.But compile return error how to write XOR in assembly(ARM)

```
XOR r1,r1,r0;
```

compiler gives like error,

```
 Error: bad instruction `xor r1,r1,r0'
```

Answer (score 13):

The instruction is called [`EOR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0005a/a51_op_xor.htm) not `XOR` as one would expect.
No idea why.

Comment: Exclusive OR makes perfect sense.  eXclusive OR is the one that is odd...

Comment: @dwelch Good to know. Didn't expect that as XOR is much more common nowadays.

Comment: Actually I havent seen EOR used except for ARM.  Both are pretty obvious as to where they come from.

Comment: @dwelch Ah, I was saying no idea why they didn't go with, what I thought, the more common `XOR`.  I researched a bit and it seems there are a number of older architectures (m86k, 6502, IBM 1130) that called it `EOR` too.

Comment: There's an ARM engineer out there that decided the mnemonic for this instruction reading this answer, sighing, and saying softly "thanks for noticing."

Comment: I've always seen words started with "ex" be abbrivated as X